# How to send an email using workflow, whenever an item is added to a list using Email

Tags: email

Ok, so whenever somebody adds an item to a list by sending an email to it, I need an email to go out to someone to let them know theres a new item.

Currently I have this working so that it will send out an email when a item is added manually, but for some reason it wont work when i send in items via email...

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, workflows are not triggered on lists or libraries with incoming email enabled. This needs to be manually enabled with powershell.

```
$spWebService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$spWebService.DeclarativeWorkflowAutoStartOnEmailEnabled = $true
$spWebService.Update()
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4607.sharepoint-2010-workflows-on-incoming-emails-in-sharepoint-documents-library.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eric! How do I access that code to change it? I havent worked with code on sharepoint before.

Comment: It has to be run in a sharepoint management shell on one of the sharepoint servers